# How do I use an inner (nested) class created with a groovy AST transformation?

Tags: java, groovy, annotations, classpath, abstract-syntax-tree

I am trying to use groovy to write an annotation and ASTTransformation which will create an inner class.

Here is the annotation:

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.transform.GroovyASTTransformationClass;

import java.lang.annotation.*;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@GroovyASTTransformationClass("WithInnerClassTransformation")
public @interface WithInnerClass {
  public String name();
}
```

And the transformation:

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.ast.*;
import org.codehaus.groovy.control.*;
import org.codehaus.groovy.transform.*;

@GroovyASTTransformation(phase = CompilePhase.CANONICALIZATION)
public class WithInnerClassTransformation implements ASTTransformation {
  public void visit(ASTNode[] nodes, SourceUnit source) {
    ClassNode outer = nodes[1];
    String name = nodes[0].getMember('name').text;
    def innerClassNode = new InnerClassNode(
        outer,
        "$outer.name\$$name",
        ClassNode.ACC_PUBLIC,
        new ClassNode(GroovyObject),
    );
    def compilerConfiguration = source.getAST().getUnit().config;
    def compilationUnit = new CompilationUnit(compilerConfiguration);
    compilationUnit.addClassNode(innerClassNode);
    compilationUnit.compile();
  }
}
```

A simple usage of the above:

```
@WithInnerClass(name = "InnerClass")
public class OuterClass {}
```

Using the following script, I confirmed that the generated class is accessible through the system class loader.

```
def classLoader = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader()
Class inner = classLoader.loadClass("OuterClass\$InnerClass")
assert inner.simpleName == "InnerClass"
assert OuterClass.declaredClasses.toList().contains(inner)
println OuterClass.InnerClass.class
```

However, when I attempt to explicitly make use of the class, I receive this error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: InnerClass for class: OuterClass
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeStaticMissingProperty(MetaClassImpl.java:997)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.getProperty(MetaClassImpl.java:1852)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.getProperty(MetaClassImpl.java:1828)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.getProperty(MetaClassImpl.java:3735)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.ClassMetaClassGetPropertySite.getProperty(ClassMetaClassGetPropertySite.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callGetProperty(AbstractCallSite.java:291)
    at main.run(main.groovy:5)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:324)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1208)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1017)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.invokePogoMethod(InvokerHelper.java:914)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.invokeMethod(InvokerHelper.java:897)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.runScript(InvokerHelper.java:407)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper$runScript.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:128)
    at main.main(main.groovy)
```

Additionally, attempting to use an import results in this error:

```
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
main.groovy: 1: unable to resolve class OuterClass.InnerClass
 @ line 1, column 1.
   import OuterClass.InnerClass
   ^
```

Comment: What is the inner class for? This seems like it needs a design tweak. (I'll also note that it's not usual to call `compile()` yourself; you usually just visit, make the modifications you need, and let the rest of the compilation process proceed.)

Comment: In this particular case, if `compile()` is not called, then `classLoader.loadClass("OuterClass\$InnerClass")` will throw a ClassNotFoundException.

Comment: Does the behavior change if you add `@CompileStatic` to `OuterClass`?

Comment: No change in behavior

Comment: And this happens even when you run the compile as a standalone step, producing `.class` files, or only when you run it all inline in a Groovy script?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that in order to explicitly use a generated class, a couple extra rounds of compilation are required. To make this code run correctly (and even be able to import the generated class), compile in 3 steps.

```
groovyc WithInnerClass.groovy WithInnerClassTransformation.groovy
groovyc OuterClass.groovy
groovyc main.groovy
```

WithInnerClass.groovy and WithInnerClassTransformation.groovy must be compiled separately from OuterClass.groovy in order for an OuterClass$InnerClass.class file to be generated.

Additionally, OuterClass.groovy must be compiled separately from main.groovy. While OuterClass$InnerClass.class will appear in the classpath in this case, for reasons I'm not clear on, this is insufficient to be able to explicitly use InnerClass inside of main.groovy. Compiling main.groovy separately, groovyc is able to pull in the "real" class file.